# Show a function such that $f'(c)\neq \dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ for any $a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Could you help me with the following please:

Give an example of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that has a point $c$ such that $f'(c)$ is not equal to the difference quotient $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ for any $a<b$. Why does this not contradict the mean value theorem?

In a graphical way what can be seen is that this occurs when the second derivative of $ f $ is 0, but trying to find this function, I have considered a polynomial with this property, but I cannot see that it fulfills this characteristic. One attempt has been to consider the $ f(x)=x^3+3x+2 $, but it failed to conclude that this is an example of what the exercise asks of us.

And well, I think this does not contradict the MVT for the domain of said function.

Comment: $ \neg(\exists x )  $ is $\forall x $

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt is close, but instead try $f(x) = x^3$, so $f'(x) = 3x^2$. Using $c = 0$ then gives $f'(0) = 0$, so for it to equal $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$ for some $a \lt b$ requires $f(b) = f(a)$. However, apart from at $x = 0$, $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, so $f(b) = f(a)$ only if $b = a$.

Regarding why this doesn't contradict the mean value theorem, note the theorem only states there exists a $c$ which meets its condition (i.e., $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$) for any specific start & end points of $a$ and $b$, not that the derivative of every point within the range must satisfy the condition for some specific start and end points.

Comment: Fantastic example of a "hidden converse".  When learning a theorem, I try to ask "What is the converse that is _not_ being stated?" For MVT, I would say "If for every $a, b$, there exists a $c$ s.t.... is $f$ necessarily continuous? No."  You're noting a second converse "If there exists a $c$... does there necessarily exist $a,b$ s.t....? No."

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=|x-2|$. then for $x \in [1,3]$ we can write
$$\frac{f(3)-f(1)}{3-1}=0\ne f'(c)$$
note that $$f(x)=(x-2), x>2, f(x)=-(x-2), x \le 0 
\implies f(x)=1, x>2; f'(x)=-1, x\le 2$$